# Mysql result row to string, UNION

Tags: mysql, union

I have a table named tblClients with the next fields:   idClient, name, credit, debt.

```
Create table tblClients(idClient int,name varchar(20), credit int, debt int);
insert into tblClients values(1,'Guillermo',1000,0),(2,'Jess',5000,2000);
```

I want to categorize the type of debt like

```
debt = 0 NOT                DEBTOR
debt between 0 AND 1000     LOW DEBTOR
debt between 1001 AND 2000  MEDIUM DEBTOR.
```

If I make this query I get the debtors type.

```
SELECT name AS 'Client',debt AS 'Debtor Type' FROM tblClients WHERE debt = 0;
SELECT name AS 'Client',debt AS 'Debtor Type' FROM tblClients WHERE debt BETWEEN 1 AND 1000;
```

How can I put the tag `DEBTOR`, `LOW DEBTOR` or `MEDIUM DEBTOR`  in the column debt instead of the debt number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT name AS Client, 
CASE 
    WHEN debt = 0 THEN 'Not Debtor'
    WHEN debt BETWEEN 1 AND 1000 THEN 'Low Debtor'
    ELSE 'Medium Debtor'
END AS debt
FROM tblClients
```